# How do I set the background color of a textbox to it's own value when the page loads

Tags: javascript

I thought this would work:

```
<input type="text" id="ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater" OnLoad="this.style.backgroundColor=this.innerHTML"
```

But that gets me:

> Identifier expected

I know that the value of the textbox is a valid HTML color value.

Comment: `input` values with `type` text will have a `value`, not `innerHTML`

Comment: Only elements which have content loaded from an external resources (like body, img, script etc.) have onload method. Also, input element doesn't have innerHTML, it is an empty element. Why not just give the default color using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

onload attribute won't work on inputs. you need to done it inside the javascript tag.
this should do the job :)

some inputs

```
<input type="text" id="ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater" value="green" />
<input type="text" id="ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater" value="black" />
<input type="text" id="ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater" value="blue" />
```

JS

```
//wait for the page to load
window.onload = function(){

//target all inputs first
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i< input.length; i++){
    //filter out inputs which have id attribute
    if(input[i].hasAttribute("id")){
        //now check if they have ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater
        if( input[i].getAttribute("id").indexOf('ThisIsDynamicAsItsInARepeater') >= 0){
            //finally change color
            input[i].style.backgroundColor = input[i].value;
        }
    }
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, we can use class instead of id. Thanks for pointing out.